# pdf to text conversion using oracle package

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, pdf, plsql

i m seeing some strange behavior for my pdf to text conversion using oracle
bellow is the code of a sql file.

```
create or replace directory pdf_dir as '&1';  
create or replace directory l_curr_dir as '&3';  
declare  
ll_clob  CLOB;  
l_bfile BFILE;  
l_filename  VARCHAR2(100) := '&2';  
begin  
begin  
ctx_ddl.drop_policy('test_policy');  
exception  
when others then  
null;  
end;  
ctx_ddl.create_policy('test_policy','ctxsys.auto_filter');  

l_bfile := bfilename('PDF_DIR',l_filename);  
dbms_lob.createtemporary(ll_clob, true);  
ctx_doc.policy_filter(  
      policy_name => 'test_policy'  
     , document => l_bfile  
     , restab => ll_clob  
     , plaintext => true  
     );  
ll_clob := REPLACE(TRIM(ll_clob), chr(13), chr(10));  
ll_clob := REPLACE(ll_clob, chr(10), chr(32) || '<<EOL>>' || chr(10)||'<<BOL>>');  
INSERT into tempclob_op(filename, data) VALUES(l_filename, ll_clob);  
DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file (ll_clob,'L_CURR_DIR' , 'plaintext.text');  
dbms_lob.freeTemporary( ll_clob );  

end;  
/
```

problem is i have run this code for 10000 files and it gives correct results for almost      all but for almost 10 files it corrupts the output in plaintext.text file. And i dont know   why is it happening? Also when i run this sql code for individual files it gives me correct results.

Comment: Not all PDF files allow for proper text extraction. Can you share a problem file for analysis?

Comment: actually there is no problem file, if I try to use the same pdf separately then it converts it perfectly, the only problem comes when i trigger below sql in a loop and try to execute it for 3 or 4k files.

Comment: I suspect some variable or object initialization issue or memory issue.. :(

Comment: Reading [Oracle's page on LOBs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm),this caught my eye: "The following [..] illustrates the case where the user incurs a deep copy by passing a temporary LOB as an IN OUT parameter." Could your REPLACE operations be doing that? (Disclaimer: me no SQL Expert!)

Comment: no success yet. I did remove the replace operations as well on it...when i debug then i found that corruption took place before the replace operation

Comment: I have added some delay of 2 seconds in every execution while in loop for each file. and seems it resolved the problem strangely ..no concrete answers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some delay of 2 seconds in every execution while in loop for each file. and seems it resolved the problem strangely ..no concrete answers though.